# Use Laravel jwt-auth by Tymon to authenticate a token on specific guard

Tags: laravel, jwt

I am having trouble with my configuration for jwt.auth and I need help with how to get jwt.auth to use my tenant-users guard.

At the moment I can login and return a token correctly for the correct model on the tenants guard. I use this for generating the token

```
if ( ! $token = Auth::guard('tenants')->attempt($credentials)) {
         return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid credentials'], 401);
    }
```

However subsequent calls to protected APIs fail authentication with a 401 even though the token does not expire for 24hrs. I think I have narrowed it down to jwt.auth trying to validate the token against the 'users' provider. Proved this by copying 'App\Models\Tenant\Staff::class' to the 'providers users model'. But I want to keep both for my web and api users (inc defaults should be web). Here is the auth config:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'tenants' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'tenant-users',
    ], 
], 

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'tenant-users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Tenant\Staff::class,
    ],
],
```

Is there anywhere I can set jwt.auth to use tenant guard / tenant-users provider for subsequent  API calls? I have searched SO and no results yet. I must just be doing something wrong.

The routes are protected as below. identifyTenant simply sets the db connection to where the tenant model is stored:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['identifyTenant', 'jwt.auth']], function () {...}
```

And for completeness the Staff model extends Authenticatable, implements JWTSubject. It has a protected db connection to 'tenant'. It implements functions getJWTIdentifier and getJWTCustomClaims

This is the code that sets the tenant db. I run this in a Service Provider.

```
 public function register()
{

    $manager = new TenantManager;

    $this->app->instance(TenantManager::class, $manager);
    $this->app->bind(Tenant::class, function () use ($manager) {
        return $manager->getTenant();
    });
   
    $this->app['db']->extend('tenant', function ($config, $name) use ($manager) {

        $tenant = $manager->getTenant();
      //  dd($tenant);
        if ($tenant) {
            $config['database'] = $tenant->db;
        } 
        return $this->app['db.factory']->make($config, $name);
    });
}
```

Identify Tenant

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $domain = parse_url($request->headers->get('origin') , PHP_URL_HOST); //eg http://test.carebase.local

    $pos = strpos($domain, env('TENANT_DOMAIN'));
    $subDomain = substr($domain, 0, $pos-1  );

    if ($pos !== false && $this->tenantManager->loadTenant($subDomain, $domain)) {
        return $next($request);
    }  else {
         Log::warning('CB : unknown tenant tried to access. Host:'.' '.$domain);
        return Abort(403);
    }

}
```

Tenant Manager

```
 public function setTenant(?Tenant $tenant, $domain = '') {
    $this->tenant = $tenant;
    $this->tenant->domain = $domain;

    return $this;
}

public function getTenant(): ?Tenant {

    return $this->tenant;
}

public function loadTenant($identifier, $domain): bool {
    // Identify the tenant here
    $tenant = Tenant::query()->where('subdomain', '=', $identifier)->first();

    if ($tenant) {
        //we need domain because we want to track where tenant is calling from. inc scheme.
        $this->setTenant($tenant, $domain);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: So you're switching the database connection after a user logs in?

Comment: Middleware checks the main db that the tenant subdomain is ok, then I switch the db to log users in on their own tenant db. I expected further calls to be able to use the tenant connection when validating the token. But not sure how to set the config so it uses the tenant guard.

Comment: Might be easier to use the `tenants` guard as the default in your app and only specify a different guard on unauthenticated routes.

Comment: I get a different issue but maybe I can look into my middleware more for this.  Setting tenants as default returns an error for no database set.  Probably a timing issue between when the identifyTenant middleware runs and defaults guard running. identifyTenant is the thing that sets the dynamic db name on \Config.

Comment: Can you show your `identifyTenant` middleware?

Comment: I just remembered encountering something similar a few years ago in a multi tenancy app; we had to call `DB::purge('connection_name');`, then set the connection in the config, followed by calling `DB::reconnect('some_tenant_connection')`. It's been a while and I haven't encountered anything similar since, but it may be worth trying in your case.

Comment: I have now added the Tenant part of the code. I felt I didn't have to purge the connection because the model has a protected connection which should use the 'extended' tenant config. I will try and I presume this would be after I have called `loadTenant()` ?

Comment: Yeah I would start by adding it there and making adjustments if needed. As far as the connection goes, I believe the models will resolve the connection instance from the service container, so purging `$this->app['db']` would be what I'd try.